# What can break the relationship between the onFormSubmit function and a spreadsheet that is attached to a google form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script, google-forms

I had a working Google form, Google spreadsheet, and GAS script which would be called when the form was submitted.  It worked fine until the did (one?) of the following things:

1. Cleared out the Responses
2. Moved the sheet and the form into a folder on Google Drive by themselves (and a Google Document)
3. Modified the form a bit, moving questions around, adding them and such.

When I submit the form, the data still shows up in the sheet but my `.gs` script is not called any longer for some reason.

The script sends mail, but I also wrote a function to check my quota for sending mail from it and it says I still have some quota left for the day I can still send 89 emails:

```
function test() {
 var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
 Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
}
```

The script is 173 lines long, it doesn't seem like it's that big.

I already have the `Resources->Current Project's Triggers` setup to send an email immediately.

Is there any way to check why the `onFormSubmit` function is not being called?

Comment: Regarding bugs, outages, etc., see  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [defect listed on the Google Apps Script issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5298).

We'll have to wait it out to see when a project member responds to it, I'm assuming.

Comment: It appears that if you setup the trigger through code it will work again: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically

Comment: I guess the answer is, A SERVICE OUTAGE!  Or...rolling back to an older version of the software by nameless-faceless parties at Google.  Oh well at least they left us an out...writing code, I'm okay with that.